# SSRS - Dynamic Footer Images in the report

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS Report, we have a requirement where we need to show or hide the images in the footer based on the Boolean parameters. We have three images icon with image source assigned. We are displaying the images in the right corner horizontally aligned next to each other. All the images are coming correctly as long as if I get 'Visible' True for all the images.

But if I get visible false for any image, I am getting blank space since I assigned fixed width to the images.

Is there any way to dynamically create image source or reduce the width of the image in the expression, so that I can avoid displaying empty space in the middle.

Comment: I've downvoted the question for "ASAP" and "urgent", but the answer below seems helpful, so I have upvoted that.

Answer (score 2):

Found a work-around to this. This is what i implemented

1. I have added 3 images in the footer section [right aligned]
2. Created a dataset with 3 columns Image1, Image2 and Image3. Written a custom query to fill this columns. If 2 images configured in Website, updated first 2 columns with image names. if only one image configured in website update the Image1 column and leave others empty.
3. Assign the image sources for the footer images from the dataset. Order should be left to right and source should be Image1, Image2 and Image3.

So if all 3 columns have the values, it will display all the images. If any 2 images are configured, then it will assign sources to the right most 2 images and leave the third one empty. So I am not facing any empty space issue in between if the image is not available. Now the system is capable of showing the images dynamically based on the availability.

Answer (score 0):

- Insert a table with three columns.
- Drag and drop the images in each textbox of table according to your
  order.
- Set the "Column Visibility" properties for each column according to
  your conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But we cannot add Table in the Footer that is the limitation we have in SSRS. Is there any way to add table inside Footer or any other solutions to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to make the image display dynamic? Can you please explain the scenario?

Comment: I want my SSRS report should be converted to PDF. In the footer, i have to display facebook, twitter and few more icons in the right most corner.Based on the settings in website, i will have those parameters returned as a boolen parameters from the DB. If it is true, i need to display specific icon with the url linked to the image. If bool value is false i have to hide particular icon.it is working as long as i have true for all the parameters.if some are returning 'false',i m getting blank space,instead i need to align all the visble icons aligned to the right without blank space in between.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible in footer section to implement your case. You can try further. What I can suggest is, if you are using tabular data then you can set the number records per page say 10 records per page and add the table of images in last row of the main table. It will show first 10 rows with data and 11th row with images in each page.

Comment: But I am not only handling single table in my report. This will not resolve my issue. thanks for your suggestion anyways